# ASImageNode - Cannot assign to property: 'image' is a get-only property

Tags: swift, xcode8, asyncdisplaykit

I'm converting my iOS Project from **Swift 2.2** to **Swift 3**. Everything was going well, but when I tried to set `image` to an instance of `ASImageNode`, I got an error that said: "*Cannot assign to property: 'image' is a get-only property*".

Here is my code:

```
let imageNode = ASImageNode()
imageNode.image = myImage
```

However, it worked in Xcode 7 + Swift 2.2.

I checked the definition of the `image` by 'cmd+click', but Xcode brought me to the `-(CIImage *)image;` in `CIImageAccumulator.h` instead of `image` in `ASImageNode`.

I could access other class and property in `AsyncDisplayKit` properly but `ASImageNode.image`. If I commented all lines with accessing `ASImageNode.image`, my project was built successfully.

Comment: Which version of `AsyncDisplayKit` did you use? I'm using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.2.1, `AsyncDisplayKit` version `2.0.1` and everything work well.

Comment: I'm also using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.2.1, `AsyncDisplayKit` is `2.0.1`. I have another project as the same, and the project also works well. So it drives me crazy...

Comment: So try clean project and rebuild. When I `Cmd + click` the `ASImageNode`, it navigates me to the Swift code, not Objective C code like you showed

Comment: I have tried clean project, clean build folder, reinstall pods, delete DerivedData folder, and reboot my mac but with no luck. Xcode also navigates me to the definition in ASImageNode.swift by `cmd+click` on the ASImageNode and other properties of it's instance, such as `isCropEnabled`, `cropRect`... But not work on `image`

Comment: what if you set a breakpoint before where you assign to image and try to `po imageNode.image`?

Comment: I eventually found that I declared an computed instance properties var image: UIImage in extension ASDisplayNode to get a node's snapshot. But there is already a duplicated declaration in ASImageNode, and Xcode 8 didn't warn me about this.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked for me is updating this [library](https://github.com/RomanBambura/Swift-UIImage-PDF) .. just update all dependencies that use `UIImage` , it looks like there's no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

> "var imageee:UIImage?"

Initialize by this Hope Worked for you 
solved my problem by this way